# custom validator for warning messages in asp.net 7.0 razor pages project

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages

in an asp.net 7.0 razor pages project is it possible to create a custom validator for warning messages?
Basically display a warning message without invalidating the modelstate.
This would allow a message to be displayed without blocking processing (for example signaling forcing to a default value if the field has not been entered).
Thank you.

Comment: Not as part of the existing validation system, no. There is no such concept as a validation warning. Items are either valid, or they're not, in which case a validation error is added to ModelState.

Comment: You can use custom validator attribute for this I'm send a example soon

Comment: It would be great if you could share your scenario, so that it can be investigated accordingly. Could you please attach your code snippet?

Comment: Hi Farid,
I don't have a code to show; I was simply wondering how to display a warning message without invalidating the model state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use custom validation attribute and check if property be null set value for that.

```
public class SetDefault : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly object? _value;
    private readonly string _statue;
    //Changed lines in Update
    private readonly string _logMessage;

    public SetDefault(object? value, string status, string logMessage)
    {
        _value = value;
        _statue = status;
        _logMessage = logMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var propertyInfo = context.ObjectType.GetProperty(context.MemberName!);

        if (value == null)
        {
            propertyInfo?.SetValue(context.ObjectInstance, _value);

            var alert = context.ObjectType.GetProperty(_statue);
            //! Changed lines in Update
            var resultVal = alert!.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null) as List<Warning>; 

            resultVal!.Add(new Warning() { Code = context.MemberName, Description = _logMessage});

            alert.SetValue(context.ObjectInstance, resultVal);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Edit :** For your question in chat we need some changes

**Note :** Read again for change in `SetDefault` attribute

First add `Entity` to our `database` and change entities like this:

`User` Entity:

```
public class UserApp : IdentityUser
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? NationalCode { get; set;}


    public List<Warning> Warnings { get; set; } = new();
}
```

`Warning` Entity:

```
public class Warning
{
    [Key]
    public int WarningId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string? Code { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }



    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserApp))]
    public int UserAppId { get; set; }

    public UserApp? UserApp { get; set; }
}
```

Next add it to `dbContext` then create `CustomUserManger` and add below method to that

**Note :** If i add `CustomUserManager` to this answer will be long search the `net` its simple

```
public async Task<UserApp?> GetByEmailWithWarnings(string email)
{
    return await Users.Include(i => i.Warnings).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Email == email);
}
```

Now can check like this in `razor` page

```
public class Register : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager; //? CustomUserManager

    private readonly SignInManager<UserApp> _signInManager;

    public Register(ApplicationUserManager userManager, SignInManager<UserApp> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public bool WarningExist { get; set; } = false;

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    public void OnGet(string? returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? "/";
        Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRegisterAsync(string? returnUrl)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? "/";

        WarningExist = Input.Warnings.Any();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();

        UserApp user = new()
        {
            FirstName = Input.FirstName,
            LastName = Input.LastName,
            Email = Input.Email,
            NationalCode = Input.NationalCode,
            Warnings = WarningExist ? Input.Warnings : new(),
        };

        var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (!createResult.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Result", "Create user broken"); //! Show error
            WarningExist = false; //? Because user don't created
            return Page();
        }

        return WarningExist ? Page() : LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostWarningAsync(string? returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? "/";

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Input.NationalCode))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Input.NationalCodel", "Filed NationalCode is required");
            WarningExist = true;
            return Page();
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetByEmailWithWarnings(Input.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.NationalCode = Input.NationalCode;
            user.Warnings.Remove(user.Warnings.First(i => i.Code == "Input.NationalCode" )); //! important

            var resultUpdate = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            if (resultUpdate.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                return LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Result", "Update user broken"); //! Show error
        WarningExist = true; //? Because user don't update
        return Page();
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Filed {0} is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field {0} is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Filed {0} is not match")]
        public string ConfirmePassword { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Result { get; set; } = string.Empty; //? Just for return Error When Add user not complete


        //! Important warning
        [SetDefault("123456789", nameof(Warnings), "Your message")]
        public string? NationalCode { get; set; }

        public List<Warning> Warnings { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

And in `cshtml` use like this

```
@{
    if(!Model.WarningExist)
    {
        //First form for register
    }
    else
    {
        //Second form for remove warning
    }
}
```

**Note :** Search the `net` for use to `OnPost` page handler in `razor` page

The answer is boring but It is necessary to carefully check the codes

Excuse me from users for (Sorry Answer out of boredom but) text. English is not my national language

I hope this help you

Every where is unclear can call me

Comment: Hi Mamad,
thanks for the help but the default value is not displayed on the screen although in debug I saw that the value is set.

Comment: @stevefax Hi, Are you sure type of default value be type of prop?

Comment: if its not work i send soon another answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention that I modified your code to return an error in case of forcing like this:
if (value == null)
{
    propertyInfo?.SetValue(context.ObjectInstance, _value);
    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
}
I would like to report the forcing before the user proceeds with confirmation.
In this case the value is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: For this you must not send error to model state be valid. For know user that set value or not you can create another property in your model and set the value for that. I will edit and add example. @stevefax

Comment: @stevefax it can help you

Comment: If I understand correctly in your example the message is handled as a normal model field that is displayed after the update in the database.
Isn't it possible to ensure that the error message and the default value are displayed before confirmation so that the user is notified of the forcing made and possibly chooses to modify it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255789/discussion-between-mamad2559-and-steve-fax).

Comment: mamad2559, thank you very much for your availability and the help you gave me.